# Looking for specific kind of smart contract for my token

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I am playing around with ERC20 token creation.

Created one using this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Nje9ucd5rY

Now I want to be able to :
-Give away tokens. For example, when buyer deposits one dollar to me, I give one token to buyer.

-Generate any amount of tokens

-Burn any amount of tokens

-Transfer to given addresses

-Receive tokens on my address

As I understand, I need to find a smart contract which does that. Where can I get this kind of smart contract?

Comment: Probably it is easier to hire a solidity developer to write such contract.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "find" a smart contract which does that, since there isn't probably a token which does exactly what you need. So you need to create it.

Most of your requirements sound like pretty standard ERC20 functionality. You can start by using OpenZeppelin templates - inherit the required contracts and extend their functionality as needed.